# How I do get blogpostId firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is getting the document id from firestore.

How I do fetch Users/documentid/Comments/documentid ?

Data class:

```
public class BlogPostId {


  @Exclude
  public String BlogPostId;

  public <T extends BlogPostId> T withId(@NonNull final String id) {
    this.BlogPostId = id;
    return (T) this;
  }
}
```

AddActivity:

```
private String blog_post_id;

Oncreate
blog_post_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("blog_post_id");

btn click
final String descff = icerikedit.getText().toString();

Map<String, Object> commentsMap = new HashMap<>();
            commentsMap.put("descff", descff);
            commentsMap.put("user_id", current_user_id);
            commentsMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users/"+blog_post_id+"/Comments").add(commentsMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {


        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            Toast.makeText(FFicerikAdd.this, "Başarılı efe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent sab=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FFicerik.class);
            sab.putExtra("blog_post_id",blog_post_id);

            startActivity(sab);

        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do, and maybe simplify the question to the bare minimum code to demonstrate that?

Comment: I make blog app .Firestore collection was Users/documentid/ inside description,title,timestamp.... while users open the title .My mainactivity view just title .if users click the title pass  descriptionactivity  . Descriptionactivity not view 1. description so my view Users/documentid/Comments/documenid .

Comment: my english so bad :)  my problem it is 1. photo [link](https://imgyukle.com/i/inkedscreenshot-5-li.xKcXy)  , 2. [link]https://imgyukle.com/i/inkedscreenshot-2018-10-30-01-16-57-li-2.xKiPh    3. [link](https://imgyukle.com/i/inkedscreenshot-2018-10-30-01-16-54-li-2.xKgWM)

Comment: From the screenshots above, which `blogpostId` would you like to get? Please responde with @.

Comment: Posts/id/Comments/2.id , I need it 2. id. My problem not getting 2. id Intent FFicerik.class  @AlexMamo

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: [link](https://imgyukle.com/i/screenshot-7.5kkeA)  My problem here.Help me please :(    @AlexMamo

Comment: So to understand better, you only achieved to get the name `Mehmet` within `zSNQ...mUUF` document and you want to get also `Ahmet` within `SinifDevam` in a single query, right? Is this correct? Please responde with @.

Comment: Exactly, I need to single query . @AlexMamo

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer in a short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way in Cloud Firestore to get the name `Mehmet` which exists within the `zSNQ...mUUF` document and the name `ahmet` which exists within the `SinifDevam` document in a single query.

Queries in Firestore are shallow, they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from another top-level collection and or from a subcollections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one step. A single query may only use properties of documents in **only** a single collection.

To solve this, you should add all user objects within a single collection and query it accordingly.